# Where initialize a specialized wpf control?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

Let's say that I want create a specialized wpf control, "YellowTextBox". It will be the same of a common TextBox, but it will be... yellow!. Ok, I go to code:

```
public class YellowTextBox: TextBox
{
}
```

Now, the obvious part, I want it be yellow...

```
this.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
```

Where I put that line of code? In the constructor? In OnInitialized override? OnLoaded, etc...

There are some correct (or better) place to put that line of code?

EDIT:
*I know I can do it via styles, my question is more an "OOP" way of do it, it can be any other kind of property or field, not exactly Background Color, that selected property was just an example :/*

Comment: You want to do this via a Style. The Style should be applied to your TextBox. There is no need to inherit from TextBox unless you need to change how it works in some fundamental way.

Comment: Thanks, @briantyler, I edited to clarify my question

Comment: If Darth Vader is standing behind you MAKING you do this the wrong way, do it the wrong way in the constructor.

Comment: You should need very little (if any) initialization code because you should specify sensible defaults for anything that needs it. Other than that, stick to the established rules for custom control creation, the basics don't change too much just because it's WPF. Be careful what you initialize because you don't want to stomp all over the styling that may be applied externally.

Comment: @slugster "Be careful..." THIS is my question :/

Comment: @ClickOk The constructor precedes application of styles and templates, so in this case that's the place -- IF Vader is standing behind you, choking you every time you edit any XAML. Good WPF practice is to allow the consumer of your code to modify it as much as possible.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks, Ed. Repeat it as answer and I will mark it as accepted...

Comment: OK, then this is a really silly question, because where you initialize something will depend on what it actually is. Maybe you can do it in the constructor, maybe after the template has been applied, maybe after it has been loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really ought to initialize a specialized WPF control in the initializers for the dependency properties (for properties it introduces), and in the default `Style` (for the new properties, and for anything it inherits that needs a different default value).

But you want to do it in C#, for some reason.

In that case, we're talking about a) OOP theology, b) OOP reality, and C) WPF mechanics. In terms of *all* of those, do it in the constructor, and in WPF, in the constructor after [`InitializeComponent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.icomponentconnector.initializecomponent(v=vs.110).aspx) (if applicable, not in your case) is called. That'll precede any styles that get applied to the control in WPF, and it's good OOP practice *and* theology to initialize everything in the constructor that you didn't initialize in field initializers. A new instance of a class should be ready to go, in a consistent state that won't throw any exceptions if you start using it. So that means the initialization should be all complete at that point. Never leave any initialization to anybody else. That's a booby trap.

Do read up on [`InitializeComponent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.icomponentconnector.initializecomponent(v=vs.110).aspx), but in your specific case, the constructor for a subclass of a standard control, you won't be calling it.

A control subclass in WPF will apply styles after the constructor. It must! Before the constructor executes, it doesn't exist. "After the constructor" is basically all there is, aside from the guts of the constructor itself. You can override `OnApplyTemplate()` to hook into things immediately *after* the template is applied. But that's much too late to be initializing much (with the exception of private fields which will refer to template children).

So if you initialize stuff in the constructor(s), it gets applied to every instance, and if it's a WPF control class (or any [`FrameworkElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.style(v=vs.110).aspx) subclass), consumers of your class can override it by applying a `Style` or a template later on. That's good WPF practice: You want to allow people maximum scope to customize your controls.